# How to load Bootstrap on wordpress home page **only**

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a wordpress site and added bootstrap to it. Now the bootstrap is messing with some of the designs on another page and the only thing I needed the bootstrap is for some cards on the homepage. please is there a way I make the bootstrap work on the homepage only?

This is the code I added to the functions.php below:

```
function bootstrap_script() {
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/styles/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_script');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbelievable but you can use function `is_home()` if you mean a blog page:

```
function bootstrap_script() {

    if ( is_home() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/styles/bootstrap.min.css');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_script');
```

Comment: It is not a blog page. It is a static home page

Comment: Than you can use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`

Comment: @pj-c0d3r You can mark this answer as accepted just click on the checkmark below the vote buttons